# Is it possible to have 2 Sharepoint 2013 Farms using the same SQL Server instance?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sql-server

Can 2 SharePoint Farms use the same database instance?    I know SharePoint can use DBs that have non-standard names (as in the case of databases that have been pre-staged). I'm not asking if they can use the same databases.  I'm asking if 2 separate 2013 SharePoint Farms can use the same instance of SQL Server?  I realize they couldn't use the same DBs- those would obviously need to be given distinct names.  I've seen that a SQL Server instance can have databases for a 2010 and 2013 farm, but I haven't seen where two SharePoint 2013 farms can use the same SQL Server instance.

If so, can anyone provide a source?

For the record, I would be using SP 2013 Standard or Foundation with a SQL Server 2012 instance.

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah it would be for 2 development instances of SharePoint.  We wouldn't be using this in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, You can. One Sql Server with two Different SharePoint Farm. Currently i have two Dev farm(2013) which are sharing the Same Database server.

- As long as you have unique Names for your Config & content DBs.
- Having Enough hardware to support both farm
- I am positive you will not do this in production, big risk. If DB server goes down...both farm will go down.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, I would separate the server in two different instances on the same SQL Server, but I don't see it being completely impossible. Make sure that you create your config database as something else, and make sure all the databases are different than what is on the first farm. Use GUIDs wisely. I don't recommend this approach though.

Answer (score 0):

When you install SharePoint, you will have to specify the database containing SharePoint configuration.  So one instance, multiple configuration databases.